# Create seperate render view

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and I'm creating a Todo App and I'm stuck with this problem where I need to separate [todos] value **completed** and **pending**.

**Todo List**

```
renderList() {
    return this.props.todos.map((todo) => {
        return (
            <div className="item" key={todo.id}>
                <div className="right floated content">
                    <div className="ui buttons">
                        <button className="ui icon green button">
                            <i className="check icon"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button className="ui icon red button" onClick={this.props.delTodo.bind(this, todo.id)}>
                            <i className="times icon"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="content">
                    <div><b>Title</b></div>
                    <div>{todo.title}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="ui middle aligned divided list">
            <h1>
                Pending
            </h1>
            {this.renderList()}
            <h1>
                Completed
            </h1>
            {this.renderList()}
        </div>
    );
}
```

My question is should I make another `renderList()` for **completed** todos ?

**Edit:**

`this.props.todos = [{ completed:false , title: "test" },{ completed:true , title: "test 2" }]`

Comment: it really depend on your data structure, you can use conditional statement inside the function or use another one.

Comment: No, you should not call the `renderList()` twice. Instead of it, you can pass the status (Pending, Completed) as a parameter and filter list according to the status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is to provide a parameter to the function, deciding which todos you want to render, attached is a working example

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const todos = [
  {title: "title1", completed: true},
  {title: "title2", completed: true},
  {title: "title3", completed: false},
  {title: "title4", completed: false}
]

const renderList = (status) => {
  return todos.filter(todo => todo.completed === status).map((todo) => {
      return (
          <div className="item" key={todo.id}>
              <div className="right floated content">
                  <div className="ui buttons">
                      <button className="ui icon green button">
                          <i className="check icon"></i>
                      </button>
                      <button className="ui icon red button">
                          <i className="times icon"></i>
                      </button>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div className="content">
                  <div><b>Title</b></div>
                  <div>{todo.title}</div>
              </div>
          </div>
      )
  })
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>completed</h1>
        {renderList(true)}
        <h1>pending</h1>
        {renderList(false)}
      </div>
    );
  }

}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/friendly-currying-v1duu?fontsize=14

Comment: you're sandbox does not look finished.But I'll try your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional statement inside `renderList`

Todo List

```
  renderList(list) {
    return this.props.todos.map((todo) => {
      if(list == "pending" && !todo.completed){
        return (
          <div className="item" key={todo.id}>
              <div className="right floated content">
                  <div className="ui buttons">
                      <button className="ui icon green button">
                          <i className="check icon"></i>
                      </button>
                      <button className="ui icon red button" onClick={this.props.delTodo.bind(this, todo.id)}>
                          <i className="times icon"></i>
                      </button>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div className="content">
                  <div><b>Title</b></div>
                  <div>{todo.title}</div>
              </div>
          </div>
      )
      }else{
        return (
          // your code for completed todos
       )
      }
    })
}
```

And in the render function

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="ui middle aligned divided list">
            <h1>
                Pending
            </h1>
            {this.renderList("pending")}
            <h1>
                Completed
            </h1>
            {this.renderList("completed")}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that if the data from where coming 
to make code more reader and more distracter it should do that not must
you can do that by adding the new component want to create props his name todos

shape to  make it

```
const NewCOMPONENT=(props)=>(
  props.todos.map((todo) =>
         (
            <div className="item" key={todo.id}>
                <div className="right floated content">
                    <div className="ui buttons">
                        <button className="ui icon green button">
                            <i className="check icon"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button className="ui icon red button" onClick={props.delTodo( todo.id)}>
                            <i className="times icon"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="content">
                    <div><b>Title</b></div>
                    <div>{todo.title}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )))
        export default NewCOMPONENT;
        // in new  the old component

        class oldCompoment extends React.Component{
        render() {
          return (
              <div className="ui middle aligned divided list">
                  <h1>
                  <NewCOMPONENT todos={DATA}delTodo={WHAT WANT TO DO AS FUNCTION} />
                  </h1>
                  <h1>
                      Completed
                  </h1>
              </div>
          );
      }}
```